# Reading more than one file in Dart

Tags: dart

I am trying to read more than one file so that I may extract information from each of them. When I try to read the second file I get

:Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

I have have an object named file and I have tried to set it to null before initializing the new file.

This is the function where the error comes from:

```
    Future readFile() async {
      print("What text file would you like to read?(Don't forget the .txt)");
      var fileName = stdin.readLineSync();
      file=null;
      file = File(fileName);
    }
```

This is the method I call

```
  addExamGrade()async{
  await readFile();
  await file.readAsLines().then((lines) =>
      lines.forEach((l) => addIndividualEx(l))//print(l)
  );
}
```

I read the information from the file here:

```
addIndividualEx(String line)async{
  var split;
  var grade;
  String fname;
  String lname;
  double ExGrade;
  if (line != null) {
    split=line.split(',');
    grade=split[1].split(' ');
    lname=split[0];
    fname=grade[1];
    ExGrade=double.parse(grade[2]);
    if(!students.containsKey(fname)){//checks first name)
      students[fname]=Student(fname, lname);
    }
    students[fname].addExamGrade(ExGrade);
  }
}
```

I would like to read more than one file.
But instead I get the error:

```
Unhandled exception:
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:147:60)
1      addIndividualHW (file:///C:/Users/Andrea%20Fernanda%20Torr/IdeaProjects/TestDart/bin/main.dart:117:16)
<asynchronous suspension>
2      addHomeworkGrades.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/Andrea%20Fernanda%20Torr/IdeaProjects/TestDart/bin/main.dart:70:28)
3      List.forEach (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:283:8)
4      addHomeworkGrades.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Users/Andrea%20Fernanda%20Torr/IdeaProjects/TestDart/bin/main.dart:70:13)
5      _RootZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1379:54)
6      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:137:18)
7      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:678:45)
8      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:707:32)
9      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:522:5)
10     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:552:7)
11     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
12     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
13     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:116:13)
14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:173:5)
```

Comment: Can you make a small complete example which we can run and which show the problem?

Comment: You aren't reading a file in `readFile`. You are assigning something to `file` - I'm not sure if that is a field or a global.  The intermediate assignment to `null` is not accomplishing anything. Nothing in this function will throw the error you are seeing. Most likely you are hitting a problem with reassigning `file` and then later trying to use it as if it had the old value. Maybe you want instead a `List<File>` and using `.add` in this function instead of reassigning?

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like the error occurs in the `addIndividualHW` function. Can you post that, too?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/dart-io

You're creating an `async` function, but you're not `await`ing anything!